# Oracle procedure to create_person fails with PLS-00306 error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a package specification:

```
G_PKG_NAME   CONSTANT VARCHAR2(30) := 'XX_CUST_PKG';
PROCEDURE customer_load
( errbuff OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2
, retcode OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2);
```

And body with procedure which calls to HZ_PARTY_V2PUB API. It uses cursor to take data from a table and then sends it to API :

```
PROCEDURE create_customer
( errbuff OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2
, retcode OUT NOCOPY VARCHAR2)
IS

ERR_SOURCE   CONSTANT VARCHAR2(100) := G_PKG_NAME ||'.create_customer'; 

CURSOR c_load 
IS 
  SELECT    rowid               row_id
  ,         person_first_name  
  ,         person_last_name   
  ,         title              
  ,         known_as           
  ,         person_identifier  
  ,         gender             

  FROM      xx_customer_info
  WHERE     NVL(status_flag, 'X') <> 'S';

r_load c_load%ROWTYPE;      
--p_init_msg_list VARCHAR2(1) := FND_API.G_TRUE;    
v_gender        VARCHAR2(30); --hz_parties.sex%TYPE;
v_title         VARCHAR2(60); --hz_parties.title%TYPE;

--API record type 
person_rec      HZ_PARTY_V2PUB.PERSON_REC_TYPE;

-- API output variables
x_return_status VARCHAR2(1);
x_msg_count     NUMBER;
x_msg_data      VARCHAR2(2000);
x_party_id      NUMBER;
x_party_number  VARCHAR2(30);
x_profile_id    NUMBER;

EXC_VALDN_ERR EXCEPTION;

BEGIN

  errbuff := ' ';
  retcode := RTN_SUCCESS;

  msg_log ('Inside '||ERR_SOURCE);

  FOR r_load in c_load LOOP

    BEGIN 
      x_msg_data      := NULL;
      x_return_status := fnd_api.G_RET_STS_SUCCESS;

      fnd_msg_pub.initialize;

      -- example validation: 
      IF r_load.person_first_name IS NULL THEN 
        x_msg_data := ' "First name" cannot be null';
        RAISE EXC_VALDN_ERR;
      END IF;

      -- Same validation for person_last_name here

      -- Record Type:

      person_rec.person_first_name  := r_load.person_first_name;
      person_rec.person_last_name   := r_load.person_last_name;
      person_rec.person_title       := v_title;
      person_rec.known_as           := null;
      person_rec.gender             := v_gender;  
      person_rec.created_by_module  := 'TCA_V2_API';



      HZ_PARTY_V2PUB.create_person ( p_init_msg_list => FND_API.G_TRUE
                                   , p_person_rec    => person_rec
                                   , x_party_id      => x_party_id
                                   , x_party_number  => x_party_number 
                                   , x_profile_id    => x_profile_id
                                   , x_return_status => x_return_status
                                   , x_msg_count     => x_msg_count
                                   , x_msg_data      => x_msg_data);

      msg_log('==========================');
      msg_log('first name / last_name : '||r_load.person_first_name||' | '||r_load.person_last_name);
      msg_log('x_return_status: '||x_return_status);
      msg_log('x_msg_count: '||x_msg_count);
      msg_log('x_msg_data: '||x_msg_data);

      IF NVL(x_return_status, FND_API.G_RET_STS_ERROR) <> FND_API.G_RET_STS_SUCCESS THEN 
        IF NVL(x_msg_count, 0) > 1 THEN
          FOR i IN 1..x_msg_count LOOP
            x_msg_data := x_msg_data||i||'. '||substr(fnd_msg_pub.get(p_encoded => fnd_api.g_false ), 1, 255)||' , ';
            msg_log(x_msg_data);
          END LOOP;
        END IF;     
      END IF;

      msg_log('==========================');

    EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        x_msg_data      := 'EXC: '||NVL(x_msg_data, SQLERRM);
        x_return_status := FND_API.G_RET_STS_ERROR;
    END;


    UPDATE xx_customer_info
    SET    status_flag = x_return_status
    ,      error_message = x_msg_data
    WHERE  rowid = r_load.row_id;

  END LOOP;

  COMMIT;

  msg_log ('Exit '||ERR_SOURCE);      

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN   
    ROLLBACK;
    msg_log('ERROR : '||ERR_SOURCE||' : '||NVL(SQLERRM, x_msg_data));
    errbuff := 'ERROR : '||ERR_SOURCE||' : '||NVL(SQLERRM, x_msg_data);
    retcode := RTN_ERROR;   

END create_customer;
```

It should return errors or success.

When I test and run this in anonymous block:

```
begin
 XX_CUST_PKG.create_customer;
end;
```

I get error message PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CREATE_CUSTOMER'. I can't see clearly where this error is referring to. I only have 2 OUT parameters, it should only give *errbuff* (which is x_msg_data) and *retcode* which is RTN_SUCCESS, RTN_WARNING or RTN_ERROR (I have this declared as constants '0', '1', '2') to output.

This was rewritten from initial package to the above example code, so that it handles exceptions, and few things had to be modified, but now I'm confused when testing it.

What did I leave out?
Any help?

Comment: You create a procedure with parameters, but wont pass one, when you call!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is a `PL/SQL` compilation error, as you can see the error code starts with `PLS-XXXX`.. So it is not returned from your procedure. You missed to send the variables to hold the values from your procedure (out arguments)

```
   Declare
      errbuf varchar2(4000);
      retcode varchar2(10); 
   begin
     XX_CUST_PKG.create_customer(errbuf,retcode);
     --printing the values
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(retcode||' '||errbuf);
    end;
    /
```

Comment: Hm, yes, I didn't call for out arguments, this was a large gap. Of course, its working now, thanks.